# Dart cannot import files

Tags: dart, import

I'm trying to create a simple web app with Dart.

But I cannot import anything that is outside the current or in a sub directory. I'm using VSCODE

My project structure:

```
/chatapp
 /web
   /main.dart
 /bin
   /server.dart
 /views
   /view.dart
   /chatsignin.dart
```

Now I can import view.dart in chatsignin.dart but cannot import view.dart to main.dart or bin/server.dart. Or any of the other file to any other file in a different directory.

I tried import with package name:

```
import 'package:chatapp/';
```

But it shows no subdirectories or files in VS Code

I tried pub get and restarted vscode multiple times but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the docs I found that all files and folders should be inside the web directory.

I'm embarrassed of myself doing such a silly mistake